# Trying to construct closed prime ideal of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$  be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra. A subset $S$ of $A$ is called multiplicatively closed if $ 0 \notin S$ and $ab \in S$ for all $a, b \in S$.

> There exists a closed prime ideal $P$ of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $ P \cap S = \phi$

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of ideals of $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying $P \cap S = \phi.$
By applying Zorn's Lemma to $\mathcal{F}$ , I'm able to get a prime ideal $P$ which satisfies $ P \cap S = \phi$ but i ain't able to get closed prime ideal. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: What happens if you apply Zorn's lemma to the collection of closed prime ideals $P$ with $P\cap S = \emptyset$?

Comment: @QuantumSpace: How do you get upper bound of a chain? Arbitrary union of closed need not be closed?

Comment: But maybe you can take the closure of the union :) ? Closure of an ideal is still an ideal.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: Yes but i can't see why the closure won't intersect with S?

Comment: You are right. I don't see an easy fix. Where is this exercise from?

Comment: @QuantumSpace: Actually I'm trying to construct a non maximal closed prime ideal of $C[0, 1]$. That's where I need it. Do you have any reference for non maximal closed prime ideal of $C[0, 1]$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to in general since closed prime ideals of a C*-algebra are always maximal.

If $A$ is abelian, this isn't too hard to see. Let $P$ be a closed prime ideal of $A$. Then $A/P$ is $C_0(X)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ and is an integral domain. But this can only happen if $X$ is a single point, in which case $A/P$ is the field $\mathbb{C}$ and $P$ is thus maximal.